# How to open the specific file when I connect to the specific wifi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi, beagleboneblack

Just as the topic. When I connect to the wifi, How can I open the connected file which is connected to the wifi. For example, when I connect the beaglebones or rapsberry wifi, then I want to open the beaglebones and rapsberry file. What should I do in the terminal. in this way, I cannot use the normal wway to open the file, because there is no usb.

Comment: Is the file stored in raspberry memory or sent to you via wifi?

Answer (score 0):

If the wifi files are stored on the raspberry device, you can identify the WIFI by the SSID number (courtesy of elParaguayo at [rasbperry forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=66826)):

```
from subprocess import check_output

scanoutput = check_output(["iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"])

for line in scanoutput.split():
  if line.startswith("ESSID"):
    ssid = line.split('"')[1]

print ssid
```